# Envoy: Terminate SSL connection on envoy and pass the connection to backend cluster with upstream_proxy_protocol

Tags: ssl, envoyproxy

My envoy version:

```
envoy  version: d362e791eb9e4efa8d87f6d878740e72dc8330ac/1.18.2/clean-getenvoy-76c310e-envoy/RELEASE/BoringSSL
```

My envoy configuration is like below:

```
admin:
  address:
    socket_address:
      protocol: TCP
      address: 0.0.0.0
      port_value: 9901
static_resources:
  listeners:
    - name: listener_443
      address:
        socket_address:
          protocol: TCP
          address: 0.0.0.0
          port_value: 443
      listener_filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.listener.original_src
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.listener.original_src.v3.OriginalSrc
      filter_chains:
      - filters:
        - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
          typed_config:
            "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
            stat_prefix: ingress_http
            route_config:
              name: local_route
              virtual_hosts:
                - name: local_service
                  domains:
                    - "*"
                  routes:
                    - match:
                        prefix: /
                      route:
                        cluster: cluster_8080
                    - match:
                        connect_matcher: {}
                      route:
                        cluster: cluster_8080
                        timeout: 0s
            http_filters:
              - name: envoy.filters.http.router
                typed_config:
                  "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router
            upgrade_configs:
            - upgrade_type: CONNECT
              connect_config: {}
        transport_socket:
          name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
          typed_config:
            "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.DownstreamTlsContext
            common_tls_context:
              tls_certificates:
              - certificate_chain:
                  inline_string: |
                    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
                    cert
                    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
                private_key:
                  inline_string: |
                    -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
                    cert
                    -----END PRIVATE KEY-----  
  clusters:
    - name: cluster_8080
      common_http_protocol_options:
        idle_timeout: 30s
      connect_timeout: 30s
      type: LOGICAL_DNS
      dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
      lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
      load_assignment:
        cluster_name: cluster_8080
        endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
              - endpoint:
                  address:
                    socket_address:
                      address: 100.120.15.231
                      port_value: 8080
      transport_socket:
        name: envoy.transport_sockets.upstream_proxy_protocol
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.proxy_protocol.v3.ProxyProtocolUpstreamTransport
          transport_socket:
            name: envoy.transport_sockets.raw_buffer
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.raw_buffer.v3.RawBuffer
          config:
            version: V1  #$META_UPTS_PP
```

Listening on port 443 and cluster is on ip 100.120.15.231 port 8080 . I need to do SSL termination and i also need to carry forward the client ip in the proxy src headers when the envoy make call to VM 100.120.15.231 .

Is above configuration correct ?

Current observation is that TLS termination is working fine but in the tcpdump i see that the proxy heards has the src ip with envoy vm ip and client ip is not getting forwarded to

```
100.120.8.10.40738 > 100.120.15.231.8080: Flags [P.], cksum 0xe13a (incorrect -> 0xa054), seq 1:52, ack 1, win 511, options [nop,nop,TS val 1878209752 ecr 2657135603], length 51: HTTP
    0x0000:  4500 0067 b98f 4000 4006 a020 6478 080a  E..g..@.@...dx..
    0x0010:  6478 0fe7 9f22 1f90 6528 67ee 795d c0ff  dx..."..e(g.y]..
    0x0020:  8018 01ff e13a 0000 0101 080a 6ff3 34d8  .....:......o.4.
    0x0030:  9e60 abf3 5052 4f58 5920 5443 5034 2031  .`..PROXY.TCP4.1
    0x0040:  3030 2e31 3230 2e38 2e31 3020 3130 302e  00.120.8.10.100.
    0x0050:  3132 302e 3135 2e32 3331 2034 3037 3338  120.15.231.40738
    0x0060:  2038 3038 300d 0a                        .8080
```